Error 'mydomain.my.salesforce.com refused to connect' when creating static resource
I'm getting the below error when clicking "save" or "cancel" on the static resource creation page.

mydomain.my.salesforce.com refused to connect

I tried to create in developer console, but another error appears:

An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: xxxxxxxxxxxx


As a workaround, I was able to create the static resource through Salesforce Classic.
